# Ambiguous reference to member 'Int.init'

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7

After updating to Xcode7 and iOS9, I am getting the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'Int.init'" in type conversion at this line "dueDate": Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)," in swift file. Help me please.

```
var date: NSDate! //Declared in the beginning of file
var updatedTask = [
        "description": self.descriptionTextfield.text,
        "title": self.titleTextfield.text,
        "priority": self.priorityTextfield.text!.uppercaseString,
        "type": self.typeTextfield.text!.uppercaseString,
        "dueDate": Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000),
        "privacy": self.privateSwitch.on ? "PRIVATE": "PUBLIC"
    ]
```

Comment: That seems to be caused by some other part of your code, maybe some libraries you are using. The cast is working fine for me.

Comment: No, it is not related to another file.

Comment: "var date: NSDate!" is declared above the file.

Comment: As I said, this is working fine so this must be caused by some framework/library/other class (e.g. an extension is declaring another `Int.init` that is conflicting with the default one). Which frameworks do you have included in your projects?

Comment: There are 27 frameworks, I am using and same type of casting is used in other files, but the error only occurs in this file. In this file, I am using import UIKit.

Comment: Crashlytics, AssetsLibrary, LinkedIn-SDK, Media Player, CoreText, CoreLocation, Address book, FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, Faborc, ImageIO, CFNetwork, FireBase, CoreTelephony, OPENGLES, System Configuration, AVFoundation, Core Motion, Core Media, HockeySDK, Security, CoreBlueTooth, MessageUI, Foundation, Core Graphics, UIKit, CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to give compiler more information about the type solved my issues. Thanks for your help.

```
 var updatedTask : [String : Any] = 
 [
    "description": self.descriptionTextfield.text!, // <- HERE
    "title": self.titleTextfield.text!, // <- HERE
    "priority": self.priorityTextfield.text!.uppercaseString,
    "type": self.typeTextfield.text!.uppercaseString,
    "dueDate": Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000),
    "privacy": self.privateSwitch.on ? "PRIVATE": "PUBLIC"
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The minimum reproducing code would be:

```
var field: UITextField = UITextField()
let dict = [
    "foo": Int(42),
    "bar": field.text
]
```

The problem here is the type of `UITextField.text`:

Xcode6.4:

```
    var text: String! // default is nil
```

Xcode7.0:

```
    public var text: String? // default is nil
```

It's changed from `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` to `Optional`

So the dictionary literal in the above code has type

```
[
   String: Int,
   String: Optional<String>
]
```

Then `Optional<String>` cannot be bridged to `AnyObject`. That's why the compiler confuses.

To fix this, you have to force unwrap `.text` properties:

```
var updatedTask = [
    "description": self.descriptionTextfield.text!, // <- HERE
    "title": self.titleTextfield.text!, // <- HERE
    "priority": self.priorityTextfield.text!.uppercaseString,
    "type": self.typeTextfield.text!.uppercaseString,
    "dueDate": Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000),
    "privacy": self.privateSwitch.on ? "PRIVATE": "PUBLIC"
]
```

Comment: BTW, The strange irrelevant error message should be considered as bug. You should report it to https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: "Cannot invoke 'init' with argument list of type (String)" error at ""privacy": self.privateSwitch.on ? "PRIVATE": "PUBLIC"" line. Can you also please tell me, how to resolve this because of update it gives error with String literals where as privateSwitch is IBOutlet.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce that error. `privateSwitch` is `UISwitch` right?

Comment: Yes, privateSwitch is UISwitch.

Comment: private switch is declared like this "@IBOutlet weak var privateSwitch: UISwitch!"

Comment: the var updatedTask is passed here." let response = InteractConnector.addTask(updatedTask as [NSObject : AnyObject])" where PRIVATE and PUBLIC are added to NSDictionary defined in InteractConnector class.

Comment: Errors are irrelevant indeed. I solved an `Ambiguous reference to member '<'` in a `canZoomOutKey : floatA < floatB` entry just because I had an unwrapped object in the key/pair above.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, there are 2 issues. Firstly, you didn't tell the compiler what type of data your Dictionary contains ([String: Any]). Secondly, As rintaro pointed out, the text property is optional on your text field.

```
// Tell the compiler about your dictionary
var updatedTask : [String : Any] = [
    "description": self.descriptionTextfield.text!, // Force unwrap the optional text property
    // rest of dictionary members
]
```